# Reactjs App - Serve images from AWS instead of server folders

Tags: reactjs

I have a react App where users can post images. When a use posts an image, my SQL table get updated. The column imgSRC gets updated with the name of the file.
For example - mysite_1536290516498.jpg

How can the code below be modified to server images from AWS instead of destFile: `${root}/dist/posts/${filename}`?

My server code to post an image and update database is:

```
  const app = require('express').Router(),
  db = require('../../../config/db'),
  Post = require('../../../config/Post'),
  User = require('../../../config/User'),
  root = process.cwd(),
  upload = require('multer')({
    dest: `${root}/dist/temp/`,
  }),
  { ProcessImage, DeleteAllOfFolder } = require('handy-image-processor')

// POST [REQ = DESC, FILTER, LOCATION, TYPE, GROUP, IMAGE(FILE) ]
app.post('/post-it', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let { id } = req.session,
      { desc, filter, location, type, group } = req.body,
      filename = `mysite_${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`,
      obj = {
        srcFile: req.file.path,
        destFile: `${root}/dist/posts/${filename}`,
      },
      insert = {
        user: id,
        description: desc,
        imgSrc: filename,
        filter,
        location,
        type,
        group_id: group,
        post_time: new Date().getTime(),
      }

    await ProcessImage(obj)
    DeleteAllOfFolder(`${root}/dist/temp/`)

    let { insertId } = await db.query('INSERT INTO posts SET ?', insert),
      fullname = await User.getWhat('fullname', id)

    await db.toHashtag(desc, id, insertId)
    await User.mentionUsers(desc, id, insertId, 'post')

    res.json({
      success: true,
      mssg: 'Posted!!',
      post_id: insertId,
      fullname,
      filename,
    })
  } catch (error) {
    db.catchError(error, res)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this using your Http server where you have access to .htaccess file or httpd.conf file in apache http server.

Just redirect all request for /dist/posts/ to AWS Path.

Before this you need to make sure you have same directory structure in AWs S3 bucket.

So when request comes from client for  /dist/posts/image it will go to
http://aws/dist/posts/

This is also known as CDN if you google.

Comment: Thanks. So there is really no need to change any js code ? Just redirect ?